# How is a bitmap usually stored in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, bitmap, binary

This is the first time I'm storing data as a bitmap in a database, and was wondering how I should be storing it. For example, if I have four options:

```
colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green']
```

And the data is structured like this:

```
id      name        favorite_colors
1       'tom'       ['yellow', 'green']
```

I would like to store the favorite colors as a bitmap, for example, 0101 (red=0, yellow=1, blue=0, green=1).

What would be the correct way to store this?

For example, as a number?

```
id      name       favorite_colors
1       'tom'      5   -- field type = UNSIGNED INT
```

Or as raw binary?

```
id      name       favorite_colors
1       'tom'      b'0101'  -- what type would this be stored as?
```

Comment: You can use the [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) datatype. It returns the result as a comma-separated string, but stores it internally as a bitmap.

Comment: @Barmar thanks could you please show an example of how I'd create that field with the above question (and then how to insert/read from it?)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... favorite_colors SET ('red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green')`